# How to optimize dynamic search in big dataset with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

There are big datasets and I want to search some data in it. When I wrote some strings in textbox it will submit or  $watch for every single letter I wrote in the input. How can I optimize it? Is there any directive or object for this in angularjs? I consider I can handle it with the setTimeout function. When user stops writing I can call $watch function. Is there any easy or right way to do it with angularjs?

Comment: use `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"`  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-model-options` directive to adjust your model custom behavior. Use properties `updateOn` and `debounce` (delay). For instance:

```
ng-model-options="{
  updateOn: 'default blur',
  debounce: { 'default': 500, 'blur': 0 }
}"// 500ms delay for default event and no delay for 'blur' event
```

Here is the [article about it](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) in the official docs.